# Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() may get an untrusted string

Tags: c#, checkmarx, secure-coding

We use `Checkmarx` to check our project.

The result show `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` may get an untrusted string and could allow an attacker to inject an arbitrary command.

```
var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

var ls = new List<string>(args.Skip(1).Select(arg => QuoteDotNetCommandLineArg(arg)));

Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = args[0],
    Arguments = string.Join(" ", ls.ToArray()),
    UseShellExecute = false
});
```

how to prevent it?

Comment: Validate `args` before doing anything else?

Comment: On an higher level you should consider how the tool performs its evaluation. It is based on [static analisys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) or [dynamic analisys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_program_analysis)?

Comment: I guess, I am missing something: This Program calls _itself_ with the same arguments just somehow quoted?? => _"Returns An array of strings where each element contains a command-line argument. **The first element is the executable file name**, and the following zero or more elements contain the remaining command-line arguments."_

Comment: _"how to prevent it?"_ - what does Checkmarx documentation say about that?

Comment: This could allow an attacker to inject an arbitrary command, and enable a Command Injection attack.

Comment: Yes, it _could_. How do the Checkmarx guys suggest to mitigate that? Or don't they go into that at all?

Comment: I can't find any suggestion for it in report from Checkmarx. The report just marked it as a high severity risk.

Answer (score 0):

Checkmarx is picking up on the fact that you are allowing the user to run an arbitrary application from your program.  If this is the correct behaviour and not a security risk then you can go to Checkmarx and flag the warning to be ignored.

Comment: I think it's a security risk. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @zhangyujason What do you mean "you think"? Deep dive into your code and find out if it actually is a risk. By the code given in the question, I cannot even make sense of the implementation.

Comment: I'm a new hire for the project. This code doesn't make sense to me either.

Comment: If you're a new hire for a project, and you're set to tackle a potential security risk you cannot make heads nor tails of, you seek help from your fellow colleagues. Security risks are not something you should be taking lightly, and neither should the company you work for.

Comment: @zhangyujason I second Lasse. It's really no shame to seek help from someone more senior in this type of situation (or at all for that matter). There have been more than one occasion in my carreer, where I approached someone with code that made me scratch my head and they said "Oh, right. That's actually not used at all. Just throw it out." - might save you time, effort and grey hair to just ask.

Comment: I never think seek help from my colleagues is a shame. The situation is this project hasn't been upgraded for serveral years. Nobody knows it. And I just try to find out if this is a risk and how to prevent it.